# Present iTunes link inside of a WebView (prevent redirect)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, itunes

I want to display an iTunes link in a `UIWebView` e.g. `https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/burn-that-broken-bed/id1120162623?i=1120163074&uo=4`

The problem is that these links when loaded in a browser automatically redirect to the iTunes app, rather than showing the content in the `UIWebView` as I'm attempting to do.

How can I either (1) prevent the redirect so that the content is displayed (2) is there another way to form the iTunes link that will not redirect? (3) any other options?

Update:  result using ThunderStruck's code: 
[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you want to show it in the web view?  If not you could always use a SKStoreProductViewController popup which will display the actual application page and a button to install it.

Comment: I'm presenting a collection view of webviews and iTunes links are among one of the types of cells I want to display to the user i.e. Along with SoundCloud YouTube Spotify etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible work-around is to request the desktop-mode of the website, which will display the intended content instead of redirecting you.

**Using UIWebView:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "Custom-Agent"])
```

Make sure you register this custom agent *before* loading the `URLRequest`. Note that this method would apply for all `UIWebView` objects in your application. If you want just some specific views to load the desktop version, you'll need to use `WKWebView` as follows, seeing as it allows you to use a custom agent per object.

**Using WKWebView:**

First, you must `import WebKit`. Then, initialize it like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/burn-that-broken-bed/id1120162623?i=1120163074&uo=4")!
let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
wkWebView.uiDelegate = self     // Optional line - must conform to WKUIDelegate
// the line below specifies the custom agent, which allows you to request the desktop version of the website
wkWebView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)
```

**Update: (Integrating WKWebView)**

Unfortunately, you can't add a WKWebView in IB as of XCode 8, so you'll have to add it programmatically. The good news here is that you can use the `frame` of the UIWebView you created in IB to slightly ease the programmatic instantiation of the WKWebView object

Check this out: (untested code)

```
// for ease of use
extension WKWebView {
    func setDesktopMode(on: Bool) {
        if on {
            customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
            return
        }
        customUserAgent = nil
    }
}
```

And in your custom cell file

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var wkWebView: WKWebView!    // add this line
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!     // the one you created in IB
}
```

Then in your UIViewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

    let url = URL(string: "url here")!

    cell.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: cell.webView.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())   // using the webView's frame that was created in IB
    cell.wkWebView.uiDelegate = self     // Optional line - must conform to WKUIDelegate
    cell.wkWebView.setDesktopMode(on: true)  // true = loads desktop mode (for your iTunes URLs)
    cell.wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution...not perfect for my use case as I am loading other non-iTunes Urls into my collectionview (e.g. Amazon, SoundCloud, Spotify etc.) nonetheless giving you credit for answering the question.

Comment: So each collection view cell has a UIWebView? If that's the case, try to change them to WKWebView instead so you can specify the `customUserAgent` per cell to suit your need. If that's not the case, tell me what it is so I could try to update my answer to fit your question better. Just want it to be fair for you :-)

Comment: Thanks!  Yes each collection view cell has a UIWebView, I couldn't figure out how to change them to WKWebView given that it's not available to drag and drop from IB?  In other words, UIWebView is all that is available in interface builder to drop into a custom cell.

Comment: Sure thing! I updated my answer. Let me know if this doesn't fix your problem, I don't mind updating it again! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks, while your original code worked in a Playground to display an app store page, when I implemented your updated answer in my project I'm getting a redirect page still, in the simulator this page is displayed...on device when you scroll over the cell you're redirected to the App Store